# Timer in jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am developing a Quiz application using Rails. Some tests are timed. I need to be able to force the candidate to submit the test once the time runs out. How do you achieve this? Refreshing the page does reset the timer right?

Comment: Check this out...  http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: I disagree with the addition of the `countdowntimer` etc. tags; more importantly, I disagree with the removal of the `ruby-on-rails` tag.

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry. I am new to this. Just wanted to get some ideas. Sorry for not specifying all the ideas on my mind!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Some suggestions

1. Do not allow the user to refresh the website.
2. Get the end time from server or duration from server.
3. Use a jQuery timer, see [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/), [here](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/timers), etc. and give it from the server side.

Comment: I don't think #1 is possible, unless you mean "without dire consequences".

Comment: @JanDvorak Say the quiz has the whole form in a page... What say now? Dire consequences? What are they?

Comment: I can't see how it's possible to prevent the page reload browser action. It is possible to terminate the quiz if this happens, however.

Comment: No you can't prevent it. Just **warn** the user about reloading page will let go of your answers. They will put a lock to `F5` key! :P

Comment: I'm not sure it's even possible to prevent the `F5` key.

Comment: No but you can frighten people by saying something.

Comment: Note that firefox will hide the user message and only display a static text in the sense of "do you really want to exit this page and lose all unsaved data?"

Answer (score 1):

In our testing software, we kept a "starting time" in the database for the displayed question.

- When the question page is refreshed, we pull start time from the database and show `Time.now- start_time`, counting backwards. So no time is lost.
- When the user tries to move to another question, we check start time and allotted time and move the user back to the correct question.